# python error when importing from __init__ file

Tags: python-2.7, python-import

I have a package installed in my site-packages dir.  Folder structure looks like this

```
MyPkg\
  __init__.py

  LogUtils\
    __init__.py
    logwrapper.py

  Shortcuts\
    __init__.py  <-----this references LogUtils
    somefile.py
```

When I do `help ('modules')` I see `MyPkg` listed.  But I get the following error in IDLE:

```
>>> import MyPkg
>>> from MyPkg import LogUtils
>>> from MyPkg import Shortcuts

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    from MyPkg import Shortcuts
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MyPkg\Shortcuts\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from GoToUrl import go_to_url
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\MyPkg\Shortcuts\GoToUrl.py", line 1, in <module>
    from LogUtils import logger, log
ImportError: No module named LogUtils
```

Why would LogUtils import fine standing alone, but throw an error when being imported via an init file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see yourself, you are not importing the same module:

```
>>> from MyPkg import LogUtils
```

vs.

```
from LogUtils import logger, log
```

The first imports a package called `MyPkg.LogUtils`, the second imports a package called `LogUtils`. Whether they exist or not depends on your python paths, but in general, if the first one works, change the second one to

```
from MyPkg.LogUtils import logger, log
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me you are lacking some backslashes

```
MyPkg\
  __init__.py

  LogUtils\
    __init__.py, \
    logwrapper.py

  Shortcuts\
    __init__.py, \
    somefile.py
```